# Stanford NLP Web tools?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've just downloaded the latest version of the Stanford CoreNLP software. Where do I find the Web tools such as WebCrawler.java? I can't find them in the download provided.
TIA

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495289/what-is-a-good-java-web-crawler-library

Answer (score 3):

Stanford NLP doesn't distribute all the bits of software we've ever written.  In a case like this, I'm sure there are better, more developed, better maintained web crawlers out there....